# oracle instant client sdk header files not found linux

Tags: php, oci8

Today I tried to install oci8 using "pecl install /tmp/oci8-2.2.0.tgz" and it throws error like
**oracle instant client sdk header files not found linux**

I set ORACLE_HOME path but still, I am getting this error. Please help

```
      checking if we're on a 64-bit platform... yes
      checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /usr/lib/oracle/19.11/client64/lib
      checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... configure: error: Oracle Instant 
      Client SDK header files not found
      ERROR: `/var/tmp/oci8/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with- 
      oci8='instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/19.11/client64/lib'' failed
```

What to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Instant Client 'devel' package that matches the 'basic' package you installed.   If PHP is 64 bit, then the packages are [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html).  Use the latest 'release update' of both.  I.e. use 19.14.

Comment: Devel package will work? which one I should install? OL8 or OL7 RPM?

Comment: Good question, but luckily the binaries are the same. They are just signed differently.  I expect both will install for you.